# How to pass [HttpGet] list variables to [HttpPost] in mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My problem is list variables,when i add variable to list ,variable add to list properly in HttpGet,when i pass same variable in HttpPost,variable not passing,why variable not passing to HttpPost,Please help me to solve this problem,i am giving my code below please check.

```
 List<tbl_Basket2> basket2 = new List<tbl_Basket2>();

 [HttpPost] 
 public ActionResult Basket(tbl_Basket2 basket2)
 {
             int qty=basket.int_Qty ;
             return View(basket2);

 }


             view page,


            foreach (var item in Model)
                {    
                 @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.dec_Price)
                  @Html.EditorFor(m => item.int_Qty)
                  @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.TotalPrice)
                 }
```

Comment: what is `basket` in POST method?

Comment: @model  IEnumerable<Project.tbl_Basket2>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Basket";
}

Comment: shouldn't the post accept a list/enumerable of tbl_Basket2 rather than a single instance?

Answer (score 0):

In the controller: -

```
public ActionResult Basket(tbl_Basket2 basket2)
```

change to:

```
public ActionResult Basket(List<tbl_Basket2> basket2)
```

change the view model to use `@model List<tbl_Basket2>` instead of an Ienumerable as the Model.

change the view to use a for - next loop: -

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
  { 
   for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)  
   {
       @Html.DisplayFor(m => item[i].dec_Price) 
       @Html.EditorFor(m => item[i].int_Qty) 
       @Html.DisplayFor(m => item[i].TotalPrice) 
   } 
}
```

That should play nicely with the MVC deserialiser model binder.

Comment: sir i am using this now but this is also not working.